# HTTP status code for associating resources

Tags: rest, api, http, http-status-codes, http-response-codes

Suppose I have 2 resources (models) in my service: `Degree`, `Course`.
When a user sends a post request to the rest API `https://example.com/degrees/degreeId/courses`
with data like `[courseId => 2]` 
It associates `Degree` with id 1 to a `Course` with id 1. 
What should status code be for representing this update?
Should I return `200` or `201`.
Also what do you suggest for response body?  The updated `Degree` along with associated `Courses`?

Comment: What resource did you create to warrant a 201 code?

Comment: No resource is created in fact, only a record is added to the pivot table ( course_degree table for example).

Comment: Then why would you consider a code that means "The request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created"?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just confused a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the big picture of your API. It somehow seems that a specific course (the ID of which you provide in the request body) should be its own resource.

However given the description, I see two possibilities:

1) Create a new resources, such as

```
/degrees/1/course/2
```

This resource could for example be used to issue a later `DELETE` request. 
In this case you can return `201` and include a `Link` to the newly created resource.

2) If there is no such resource, `200` seems to be the only applicable positive response.

Option 1 seems preferable to me.

Comment: Yep Course and Degrees are separate resources on back-end.  
By visiting this url you associate these 2 resources.  So you suggest status code 200?

Comment: I have extended my answer to address your comment.